# Receiving emails from specific domain in Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

Is there a way out through which I only allow email receiving from specific domains in Amazon SES. For example - I only want to honour emails coming from domains abc.com and reject any other mails coming from different domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep!

You can invoke a Lambda function when an email received, this article explains the process in more detail.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda.html

From that document

> Writing Your Lambda Function
>
> To process your email, your Lambda function can be invoked
>   asynchronously (that is, using the Event invocation type). The event
>   object passed to your Lambda function will contain metadata pertaining
>   to the inbound email event. You can also use the metadata to access
>   the message content from your Amazon S3 bucket.
>
> If you want to actually control the mail flow, your Lambda function
>   must be invoked synchronously (that is, using the RequestResponse
>   invocation type) and your Lambda function must call the callback
>   method with two arguments: the first argument is null, and the second
>   argument is a disposition property that is set to either STOP_RULE,
>   STOP_RULE_SET, or CONTINUE. If the second argument is null or does not
>   have a valid disposition property, the mail flow continues and further
>   actions and rules are processed, which is the same as with CONTINUE.
>
> For example, you can stop the receipt rule set by writing the
>   following line at the end of your Lambda function code:
>
> callback( null, { "disposition" : "STOP_RULE_SET" });

Comment: Synchronous?  Nice.